# Error while running LiveAuthClient's LoginAsync

Tags: c#, windows

I'm trying to write a simple windows store app that forces a user to login right away. I'm following these guides:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh968445.aspx

And

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh826543.aspx#csharp

and I've added the following:

```
public LiveConnectSession Session
{
    get
    {
        return _session;
    }
    set
    {
        _session = value;
    }
}

private async void InitAuth()
{
    if (!Windows.ApplicationModel.DesignMode.DesignModeEnabled)
    {
        try
        {
            authClient = new LiveAuthClient();

            List<string> perms = new List<string>() { "wl.signin", "wl.basic", "wl.skydrive" };
            LiveLoginResult authResult = await authClient.LoginAsync(perms);

            if (authResult.Status == LiveConnectSessionStatus.Connected)
            {
                this.Session = authResult.Session;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            String message = e.Message;
        }
    }
}
```

I call `InitAuth()` from the `App()` constructor.

I get an "Element Not Found" Excetion, and the following stack trace:

```
   at Microsoft.Live.LiveAuthClient.<ExecuteAuthTaskAsync>d__4.MoveNext()
    End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown 
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at TuneHoc.App.<InitAuth>d__1.MoveNext() in <filename>
```

Does anyone know the problem?